# Automatically assign ip address to bridged network in VMWare Workstation?

Tags: centos, ip

[image]

This is how my servers with bridged adapters look like.

I want to assign an ipv4 address to them. How do I do it using dhcp(preferred)? Or manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bridge connection your router will assign IP from the DHCP pool. check for file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33`. If file does not exist then create one and put the content like

```
DEVICE="ens33"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT="yes"
```

and restart the network via `systemctl restart network.service`.